# Wordpress 4.4 TinyMCE javascript error Deprecated TinyMCE API call: <target>.onPaste.add(..)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I am using Wordpress 4.3 or sometimes 4.4 but every time i include editor in front user page it gives me error in console

deprecated TinyMCE API call: .onPaste.add(..)

help me

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow below steps to solve this issue.

1)  Clear browser cache to clear loaded JS.
2)  Activate 2014 WordPress theme.
3)  Deactivate all WordPress plugins.
4)  Activate your current WordPress theme.

And enjoy tinyMCE in template page.

Comment: Updating the active theme solved the problem for me. I did not deactivate and activate all plugins.